# AddressVerify API of paypal to verify the street address

Tags: paypal

I want to call AddressVerify API of paypal to verify the street address of a paypal user (with email id provided)
I used the below code and in response it says:
"You dont have permission to make this call".

I found on stackoverflow to make this API call it has to be get permission from paypal team whether it is sandbox account or live. Does anyone has paypal's support email or phone no. ?

```
$http = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
$config = array('timeout'    => 30,'verifypeer' => 0);
$request['[METHOD'] = 'AddressVerify';
$request['EMAIL'] = 'xyz@buyer.com';
$request['STREET'] = '123 xyz Road';
$request['ZIP'] = '99999';

$request['VERSION'] = '72.0';
$request['USER'] = 'xyz@merchant.com';
$request['PWD'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$request['SIGNATURE'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$request['BUTTONSOURCE'] = 'Varien_Cart_EC_US';

$http->setConfig($config);
$http->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp', '1.1', array(), http_build_query($request));
$response = $http->read();
```

Comment: Are you open to the idea of using an address verification service other than the one Paypal provides?  If you are, I think you'll find that they are more powerful, since that is their focus, except that they won't have paypal account-specific data.  A quick google search for "address verification" or "address validation" will give you a number of good candidates.

Answer (score 0):

The address verify feature is not enabled on account by default.  If this is for the sandbox, and you can provide the email address for your test sandbox seller account I can enable th is for you.  If this is for a live account, you will need to contact PayPal Merchant Services, or your account manager if you have one assigned to you and request this to be enabled on your live account.

Comment: Yes I have configured this on sandbox account. Sandbox Email: vishal.porwal@ascendum.com please enable this API for this account.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: @jeffery we have to use paypal API as we want to verfiy the address with the one filed in paypal account by user.

Comment: I have enabled the AddressVerify API on this account.  You should be able to test with this now and get a successful response back now.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I got below response for this account."Specified mehtod not supported"
 Array
 ([0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Date: Wed, 29 May 2013 12:14:57 GMT
 Server: Apache
 Content-Length: 146
 Connection: close
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 ACK=Failure
  [1] => L_ERRORCODE0=81002
  [2] => L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method
  [3] => L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported
  [4] => L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
 )
In addition to that I want to let you know that under my sandbox account I have created vishal.porwal_api1.merchant.com account for testing.

Comment: here is one confusion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828152/paypal-express-checkout-and-address-verify-api

anyone knows help appreciated!! 
Thanks

Comment: What is the account that you are trying to make the API call on.  I checked the account you previously provided and I do not see any attempts where you are trying to use the AddressVerify API.  Make sure you are pointing to the correct endpoint and using the correct credentials.  If you still get the error can you provide the correlation id from your API response?

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad In admin tools, where do I navigate to enable the Address Verify API?