# paypal Express checkout and address verify API

Tags: paypal

What is the differece between paypal Express checkout addressstatus field and AddressVerify address match field ? both does the same address check ? if yes then no need to call addressverify API if we get it in express checkout response ? Am I correct ?

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/AddressVerify_API_Operation_NVP/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 1):

The `ADDRESSSTATUS` or `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ADDRESSSTATUS` that is returned in the [GetExpressCheckoutDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) call gives you the status of the street address on file with PayPal.  The values that you would have returned for this variable are None, Confirmed, and Unconfirmed.

The [AddressVerify API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/AddressVerify_API_Operation_NVP/) allows you to verify the address without having to send the buyer through the Express Checkout flow and it will tell you if the address is a confirmed address on file with PayPal.  In addition to this, it will also tell you if the street matched, the zip code matched, and will provide the country code on file for the PayPal email address.  You will also get a token back with the [AddressVerify API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/AddressVerify_API_Operation_NVP/) that contains encrypted information about the member’s email address and postal address. If you pass the value of the token in the HTML variable address_api_token of Buy Now buttons, PayPal prevents the buyer from using an email address or postal address other than those that PayPal verified with this API call. The token is valid for 24 hours.